# How to create a loop that applies different filters to data frame

Tags: r

I apologize in advance,  my question header may not accurately describes what I am trying to do. I think what I need to create is a loop, but I will give a give more detail. I have two data frames

df1

```
chr location gene sample1 sample2 
1 12345 FAM1 0.1 0
1 124353 ABCA 1 0.5
2 12353 ALMS1 2 0.1
3 23456 TNN 0 0
7 657864 MYBC3 0.3 1
```

and df2

```
sucrose fructose glucose galactose
FAM1 FAM2 ALMS1 ALMS2
FAM2 TNN2 MYBC3 ABCA
FAM3 MYBC2 TNN ABCA2
FAM4 MYBC ABCA2 FAM3
FAM5 ALMS2 ABCA3 FAM4
```

So df1 is my main data frame and df2 contains columns that I use to filter df1. So for example I would use the first column of df2 (sucrose) and filter df1 for any of the genes in the sucrose column. So for after applying the filter the data would look like this.

```
chr location gene sample1 sample2 
1 12345 FAM1 0.1 0
```

So I have been able to do this, but the real df2 has thousands of columns. So what I want to do is some how create a loop? (if that is the correct term) that will run through all the column in df2, apply them as a filter to df1, and then save the results as a new data frame. Ideally, I would like to have the new data frame to have the same name as the column that filter it so in the example I gave the new data frame would look like this

```
sucrose
#   chr location gene sample1 sample2
# 1   1    12345  FAM1   0.1       0
```

Here is an example of the script that I run just for one column in df2

```
sucrose <- df1 %>%
  filter(gene %in% df2[[1]]) %>%
  filter(gene != "")

sucrose$Number.of.MMVD.dogs <- (sucrose$sample1 + sucrose$sample2)

sucrose <- sucrose  %>%
  filter(Number.of.MMVD.dogs >= 0.01)
```

This filter gives me the following output

```
sucrose
#   chr location gene sample1 sample2 Number.of.MMVD.dogs
# 1   1    12345  FAM1   0.1       0        0.1
```

I just don't want to have to type this out for every column that I use to filter df1. I know there is a better way to do this instead of doing it by hand, but I am not sure how to do this. I admit, it will create a lot of data frame, but I am going to save them for a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider reshaping the wide *df2* into long format with `tidyr::gather` and then join using `dplyr::inner_join` with *df1*. Finally, `split` the data frame by the new *sugar* column which returns **one** list of many data frames which is ideally more manageable than 1,000 data frames flooding your global environment:

```
longdf <- df2 %>%
  tidyr::gather(sugar, gene)

df1 <- df1 %>%
  dplyr::inner_join(longdf, by="gene")

df_list <- split(df1, df1$sugar)

# LIST OF THREE DATA FRAMES
df_list
# $galactose
#   chr location gene sample1 sample2     sugar
# 2   1   124353 ABCA       1     0.5 galactose

# $glucose
#   chr location  gene sample1 sample2   sugar
# 3   2    12353 ALMS1     2.0     0.1 glucose
# 4   3    23456   TNN     0.0     0.0 glucose
# 5   7   657864 MYBC3     0.3     1.0 glucose

# $sucrose
#   chr location gene sample1 sample2   sugar
# 1   1    12345 FAM1     0.1       0 sucrose
```

You lose no functionality of data frame if it is stored in a named list than as a separate object:

```
summary(df_list$galactose)
#       chr       location          gene              sample1     sample2       sugar          
#  Min.   :1   Min.   :124353   Length:1           Min.   :1   Min.   :0.5   Length:1          
#  1st Qu.:1   1st Qu.:124353   Class :character   1st Qu.:1   1st Qu.:0.5   Class :character  
#  Median :1   Median :124353   Mode  :character   Median :1   Median :0.5   Mode  :character  
#  Mean   :1   Mean   :124353                      Mean   :1   Mean   :0.5                     
#  3rd Qu.:1   3rd Qu.:124353                      3rd Qu.:1   3rd Qu.:0.5                     
#  Max.   :1   Max.   :124353                      Max.   :1   Max.   :0.5            

str(df_list$glucose)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ chr     : int  2 3 7
#  $ location: int  12353 23456 657864
#  $ gene    : chr  "ALMS1" "TNN" "MYBC3"
#  $ sample1 : num  2 0 0.3
#  $ sample2 : num  0.1 0 1
#  $ sugar   : chr  "glucose" "glucose" "glucose"

head(df_list$sucrose)
#   chr location gene sample1 sample2   sugar
# 1   1    12345 FAM1     0.1       0 sucrose
```

Comment: Wow.. that is a work of art. That made it so much easier to work with. I can't even believe it. Thanks so much

Comment: Glad to help! When you keep data long, processing is much easier!

Comment: One other question. I am going to need to save these different sets of filtered data. Is there an easy way to do that that with this many files? I know it seems ridiculous but I will need an actual text or excel file so other people can look at the data that don't know how to use R

Comment: The beauty of keep everything in lists, simply run `lapply` and call `write.csv`: `lapply(names(df_list), function(i) write.csv(df_list[[i]], paste0(i, ".csv")))`

Comment: Code golf: `mapply(write.csv, df_list, paste0(names(df_list),".csv"))`

Comment: @Parfait you made my day. Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: @r2evans That works like a charm too. Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

using

```
library(foreach)
library(dplyr)


df1 <- tribble(~chr, ~location, ~gene, ~sample1, ~sample2,
1, 12345, "FAM1", 0.1, 0,
1, 124353, "ABCA", 1, 0.5,
2,12353, "ALMS1", 2, 0.1,
3, 23456, "TNN", 0, 0,
7, 657864, "MYBC3", 0.3 ,1)

df2 <- tribble(
  ~sucrose, ~fructose,~ glucose,~ galactose,
  "FAM1","FAM2", "ALMS1", "ALMS2",
  "FAM2", "TNN2", "MYBC3", "ABCA",
  "FAM3", "MYBC2", "TNN" ,"ABCA2",
  "FAM4", "MYBC", "ABCA2", "FAM3",
  "FAM5", "ALMS2", "ABCA3", "FAM4"
)

foreach(i= 1:dim(df2)[2], .combine=rbind) %do% { 
sucrose <- df1 %>%
  filter(gene %in% df2[[i]]) %>%
  filter(gene != "")
sucrose$Number.of.MMVD.dogs <- (sucrose$sample1 + sucrose$sample2)
sucrose <- sucrose  %>%
  filter(Number.of.MMVD.dogs >= 0.01)
} -> your_variable
```

and the output is:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
    chr location gene  sample1 sample2 Number.of.MMVD.dogs
  <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>               <dbl>
1  1.00    12345 FAM1    0.100   0                   0.100
2  2.00    12353 ALMS1   2.00    0.100               2.10 
3  7.00   657864 MYBC3   0.300   1.00                1.30 
4  1.00   124353 ABCA    1.00    0.500               1.50
```

Comment: That isn't the output that I get when I run that. Ideally, the output should look like that I gave as an example above

Comment: the code puts all of the outputs for each sugar together in a tibble

Comment: Ooooh I see. I really need them to be in separate data frames and not in just one. Is there some way to get them into four separate data frames with the correct names?

Comment: you wanna write them down or you want objects?